# Xamarin Open closed Xamarin forms application from android OnReceive

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to open a specific Page from completely closed Xamarin Forms application on android service `OnReceive`

I set an alarm to launch the application at specific time

```
  [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true, Exported = false)]
    public class Alarm : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
            PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "");
            wl.Acquire();

            Vibrator v = (Vibrator)context.GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
            v.Vibrate(1000);

            Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(myForm));
            i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            context.StartActivity(i);

        }
 public void SetAlarm(Context context, DateTime time, string uniqName)
            {
                AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
                Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(Alarm));
                i.SetAction(uniqName);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);

                //var totalMilliseconds = (long)(time - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
                DateTime st = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                TimeSpan t = (time.ToUniversalTime() - st);
                var totalMilliseconds = (Int64)(t.TotalMilliseconds + 0.5);

                am.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, totalMilliseconds, pi);
            }
    }
```

When I try this code i got this error

```
Unhandled Exception:

System.ArgumentException: type
Parameter name: Type is not derived from a java type.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xamarin.Forms run on a single activity, so if you handle the OnReceive on a different class, make sure to switch to the MainActivity from where you can use the normal navigation. 
Should be something like this:

```
public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.PowerService);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.NewWakeLock(WakeLockFlags.Partial, "");
    wl.Acquire();

    Vibrator v = (Vibrator)context.GetSystemService(Context.VibratorService);
    v.Vibrate(1000);

    Intent i = new Intent(context, typeof(MainActivity));
    i.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
    i.PutExtra("alarmIntent",Intent.Data);
    context.StartActivity(i);
    this.FinishActivity(0);
}
```

and then in your MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    base.OnNewIntent(intent);
    Intent = intent;
}

protected override void OnPostResume()
{
    base.OnPostResume();
    if (Intent.Extras != null)
    {
        string fileName = Intent.Extras.GetString("alarmIntent");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName))
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync (new myForm());
        }
        Intent.RemoveExtra("alarmIntent");
    }
}
```

Check out this [post](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61469/how-do-i-navigate-from-an-android-activity-to-a-xamarin-forms-contentpage)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion this code works fine when application is running, but when I close application completely it crashed.

Comment: Thanks now works, but no need to **this.FinishActivity(0);**